# Bash Perl loop regex read from file

Tags: regex, bash, perl, loops

I have *data.txt*

```
aaa
bbb
ccc
vvvccccc
dddd
eeee
```

and `str.txt`

```
aaa
ccc
```

usually I search single string with

```
perl -ne 'print if(/aaa/)' data.txt
```

now I want do multiple search in data.txt that containing string in str.txt

```
while read line; do
  perl -ne 'print if(/$line/)' data.txt
done < str.txt
```

but it print content in data.txt multiple times

```
aaa
bbb
ccc
vvvccccc
dddd
eeee
aaa
bbb
ccc
vvvccccc
dddd
eeee
```

and it should be

```
aaa
ccc
vvvccccc
```

what wrong with my code, thanks and sorry if my words is wrong.

Comment: Why don't you want to use grep? It would be ideally suited to this task.

Comment: I working in large file and using perl is faster

Comment: no, I asking for help and I just want to know solution for perl

Comment: If you have more complex requirements, such as matching Perl-style regular expressions, you should edit your question to make this clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using single quotes in perl script ,single quotes treat given variable name as a literal value like $line instead of some content .
So you can try double quotes and get your expect result

```
while read line; do
perl -ne "print if(/$line/)" data.txt
done < str.txt
```

**output:**

```
aaa
ccc
vvvccccc
```

Answer (score 1):

As you have provided no good reason not to use grep, I will show you how easy it would be to use it:

```
grep -f str.txt data.txt
```

You should try it and see if it works well enough. It will almost certainly be faster than a solution based on a `while read` loop in bash and repeated calls to Perl.

If you are sure you want to use Perl, then it would make more sense to do something like this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my ($strings, $data) = @ARGV;

open my $s, "<", $strings;
chomp(my @patterns = <$s>);

open my $d, "<", $data;
while (my $line = <$d>) {
    print $line if grep { $line =~ $_ } @patterns
}
```

Although this is a few more lines than the bash loop, it is also a lot more efficient as Perl is only run (and the file `str.txt` is only read) once.

Testing it out:

```
$ perl script.pl str.txt data.txt 
aaa
ccc
vvvccccc
```

Comment: I've tried it, how to use regex for example I want to append digit like `$line\d+$`

Comment: It looks like your requirements are more complicated then. Edit your question to explain exactly what you're trying to do, showing some more interesting examples.

Comment: If you're determined to use Perl, you're better off using it to do the whole thing. See the update to my answer.